# What does this message from the Software Updater mean?

Tags: 18.04, update-manager, 32-bit

32-bit 18.04 system.

The computer hardware is 32-bit only.  There is no prospect of ever installing 64-bit software on this computer.

Today I ran the Software Updater for the first time in a long time (I normally update using the terminal).  At the conclusion of the process, this dialog box was presented.

[image]

Now, I'm well aware that Ubuntu has dropped support for 32-bit computers, but 18.04 will continue to support them until it becomes EOL. That is what the first two sentences on the dialog box are telling me.

But what does the third sentence that I have highlighted in yellow mean?

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/download **now** only offers 64-bit only downloads for supported releases. So I guess this is what it means: *reinstall Ubuntu 64-bit to get future upgrades*.

Comment: If using 32 bit on a 64 bit capable computer, you can do a clean install to a 64 bit version.  You can't upgrade from 32 bit to 64 bit, but can install a 64 bit over it.  If computer is only 32 bit then your choice is to install another distro from other Linux to keep getting updates after 18.04 EOL.

Comment: i had the same question. Ubuntu developers should have been more clear in this sentence, maybe something like "If you happen to run 32-bit Ubuntu 18.04 on a 64-bit architecture, you could install the 64-bit version to get future upgrades" ...